# How use the string in the select from table?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

How use the string in the select from table?
Example:

convert this query:

```
 DBEntities MyDB = new DBEntities();
        var Query1 = from P in MyDB.Per
        where P.IDRANK == 2
        select P;
to:


 string strquery = "where P.IDRANK == 2";
    DBEntities MyDB = new DBEntities();
    var Query1 = from P in MyDB.Per
         strquery 
    select P;
```

Comment: Use PredicateBuilder:  http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx

Comment: Can you explain why do you want that? The strongly typed syntax is supposed to be a plus for LINQ Queries.

Comment: because I want to all program, have a select.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you can do it if you can get a DataTable:

```
// Build a data table and add columns
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("IDRank");
dt.Columns.Add("Blah");

// Add rows to the table
for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
    DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
    dr["IDRank"] = i;
    dr["Blah"] = "Blah" + i.ToString();
    dt.Rows.Add(dr);
}           

// Get a DataView to table
DataView dv = dt.AsDataView();

// Define the filter
string filter = "IDRank = 2";

// Apply the filter
dv.RowFilter = filter;

// Run the query
var Query1 = from P in dv.ToTable().AsEnumerable() select P;
```

Comment: Please provide more detail.

Answer (score 0):

Each Table,I'm writing much function.I need These Convert to one function.
for Example: I have two function for Table Per

```
private void SelectByRank(int Rank)
        {
            DBEntities MyDB = new DBEntities();
            var Query1 = from P in MyDB.Per
                         where P.IDRANK == Rank
                         select P;
        }
        private void SelectByRankANDBlah(int Rank, string Blah)
        {
            DBEntities MyDB = new DBEntities();
            var Query1 = from P in MyDB.Per
                         where P.IDRANK == Rank && P.BLAH == Blah
                         select P;
        }
```

**Now, I will Convert to one function. for Example**

```
private void Select(string strKind,int Rank, string Blah)
        {
            var strWhere ="";
            if(strKind == "RANK")
            {
                strWhere  = "where P.IDRANK ==" + Rank;
            }
            else 
            {
                strWhere  = "where P.IDRANK == " + Rank + " && P.BLAH == " + Blah;
            }

            DBEntities MyDB = new DBEntities();
            var Query1 = from P in MyDB.Per
                            strWhere 
                         select P;
        }
```

OK?

Answer (score 0):

I use this code

```
using (var context = new DBEntities())
            {
                System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery<User> contacts = context.Users.Where("it.FirstName = @fname", new System.Data.Objects.ObjectParameter("fname", "Arash"));
                List<User> items = contacts.ToList();
            }
```